# Getting exp to work in spire

Tags: scala, numeric, spire

I'me learning scala for the purpose of scientific programing.  I'm trying to write some simple generic code using spire.  I've got the following example working:

```
import spire.algebra._
import spire.math._
import spire.implicits._
object TestSqrt {
    def testSqrt[T: Numeric](x: T) = {
        sqrt(x)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val x_d: Double = 4.0
        println(testSqrt(x_d))

        val x_i: Int = 4
        println(testSqrt(x_i))
    }
}
```

This prints out 2.0 and 2, as expected.  The problem is that I can't get the same thing to work with the exp function.  The following code does not compile:

```
import spire.algebra._
import spire.math._
import spire.implicits._
object TestExp {
    def testExp[T: Numeric](x: T) = {
        exp(x)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val x_d: Double = 4.0
        println(testExp(x_d))

        val x_i: Int = 4
        println(testExp(x_i))
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
... could not find implicit value for parameter t: spire.algebra.Trig[T]
[error]         exp(x)
[error]            ^  
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Am I doing something wrong, is exp not yet supported, or is this a bug?  Can anyone provide a working example of using exp with a generic numeric type from spire?

UPDATE:

I can make exp work by using Trig instead of Numeric, like this:

```
import spire.algebra._
import spire.math._
import spire.implicits._
object TestExp {
    def testExp[T: Trig](x: T) = {
        exp(x)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val x_d: Double = 1.0
        println(testExp(x_d))

        val x_f: Float = 1.0f
        println(testExp(x_f))
        // val x_i: Int = 4
        // println(testExp(x_i))
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work with Int, only floating point types.  Further, if I use Trig then I can't use sqrt.  The following code does not compile:

}

```
import spire.algebra._
import spire.math._
import spire.implicits._
object TestSqrt {
    def testSqrt[T: Trig](x: T) = {
        sqrt(x)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val x_d: Double = 4.0
        println(testSqrt(x_d))

        val x_i: Int = 4
        println(testSqrt(x_i))
    }
}
```

And gives the error:

```
... could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spire.algebra.Trig[Int]
[error]         println(testSqrt(x_i))
[error]                         ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

What should I do if I want both exp and sqrt, and is there a way to make exp work with Integral types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type classes are defined to have the same type for the operands and the results of the operations. That is to say, when you run `sqrt` on a value of type `A`, the result will also be of type `A`.

Now you may argue that `sqrt` on integers yields integers *for some specific input values*, such as 4 which you use in your example. On the other hand, what should `sqrt(5)` return? It seems it will return the greatest integer smaller than the actual square root:

```
def testSqrt[T: Numeric](x: T): T = sqrt(x)

scala> testSqrt(5)
res0: Int = 2
```

This is hardly what you want. Interestingly, when you call the `sqrt` function directly, it will return a `Double`:

```
scala> sqrt(5)
res1: Double = 2.23606797749979
```

The reason is that when you import `spire.math._` you get an overloaded `sqrt` function:

```
final def sqrt(x: Double): Double = Math.sqrt(x)
final def sqrt[A](a: A)(implicit ev: NRoot[A]): A = ev.sqrt(a)
```

This "solves" the problem by giving the first variant priority (as it doesn't require implicit parametes). What happens in your example is that you use a generic signature, therefore the second version of `sqrt` will be called. The `NRoot` argument is indirectly provided because you say you have a `Numeric`.

So you will have to decide what you are going to do—do you want to fall back to `Double` when calculating the square root, or go with this rather unconventional idea of potentially truncating the result?

---

Now to exponentiation. In `math`, there are again overloaded versions of `exp`, among them:

```
final def exp(n: Double): Double = Math.exp(n)
final def exp[A](a: A)(implicit t: Trig[A]): A = t.exp(a)
```

The difference to `sqrt` is that you won't get a `Trig[Int]` under any circumstances. There is just no meaningful way.

Let's just define a function that can call `sqrt` an `exp` based on the type classes:

```
def sqrtAndExp[T: NRoot: Trig](x: T): (T, T) = (sqrt(x), exp(x))
```

You see you can use *more than one context bound* in a function declaration. This syntax is equivalent to

```
def sqrtAndExp[T](x: T)(implicit nroot: NRoot[T], trig: Trig[T]: (T, T) =
  (sqrt(x), exp(x))
```

For doubles, this function works (given you have imported `spire.implicits._`):

```
scala> sqrtAndExp(5.0)
res2: (Double, Double) = (2.23606797749979,148.4131591025766)
```

But not for integers:

```
scala> sqrtAndExp(5)
<console>:18: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
                     spire.algebra.Trig[Int]
              sqrtAndExp(5)
                        ^
```

Integers can always be used where doubles are required, however. So you can make it work:

```
scala> sqrtAndExp[Double](5)
res3: (Double, Double) = (2.23606797749979,148.4131591025766)
```

Comment: Very clear and solves my problem.  I had no idea you could use multiple context bounds.

Comment: Obviously you can also add an overloaded function `def sqrtAndExp(x: Double): (Double, Double)` if you want to be able to call it with integer literals.